# Does anyone know what symbol this is?

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know what symbol this is? I think it is M but I'm not sure which font.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell in what context you found it?

Comment: It is in Quarks and Leptons by Francis Halzen and Alan D. Martin (a book on particle physics). It is the invariant amplitude.

Comment: it's a `\mathcal` M of some sort, but unless you are reproducing an exact text with all the same fonts in all the same circumstances does it matter exactly which font is used? Exact font recognition is mostly off topic for this site as it's unrelated to TeX.

Comment: I just like it.

Comment: it has the characteristics of a fraktur M but i don't recognize the particular font.

Answer (score 0):

It is like a M from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{aritcle}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\mathfrak{M}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mmmm, not really.

Comment: @Werner Yes in fact not really, I compare too quickly `:/`

Answer (score -1):

It is written in a calligraphical font.
[Here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html) you can find numerous caligraphical and handwritten fonts.

Comment: Soooo... where can one find it? It's not in the link you provide...

Comment: I have tried \mathcal{M} but it's not the same.

Comment: @Werner I don't know exactly the font.